# Way to use middle click drag on a href tags

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, browser

When picture `<img>` is inside `<a>` tag,

is there a way that i can still use middle click drag on like on any other ellemenet to scroll/navigate page instead of default behavior where middle click open new tab or does not scroll on drag?

I do understand that i can maybe use different tag on element and go with click event on it, but i would not wish to do it like that if possible.

Comment: Could you explain a little bit better what are you aiming to achieve?

Comment: Lets say page is 100% populated only with <a><img></a> elements (no empty spaces between them), you can scroll the page with middle mouse scroll, but you cant use middle mouse click to drag for scrolling page. I am trying to allow middle mouse drag to still scroll page even if mouse starts under <a> tag to drag.

Comment: After some research, what you are asking for seems to be very specific. What works on some browsers won't work on others. I poster my answer below, but be careful because it won't work for every user.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the `which` property. But this property is browser specific.

```
$("a").mousedown(function(event){
    if(event.which == 2){
         event.preventDefault()
    }
}
```

Comment: A more standardized approach would be to use [MouseEvent.button](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MouseEvent/button).